# Realtime task activity viewer for Android

Tags: task-management

There are many times when an app just stops responding and I'm not sure whether it's still working on something, or has just gone dead. Titanium Backup has done this on a number of occasions. If I could just see a list of apps and what memory and CPU percentage each is using, I'd have a better idea of whether to wait or kill the app.

Is there any way to show the nature of the activity going on with running apps, something like Windows [Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Manager_(Windows))?

BTW, I do not like the Android's "Wait/Force Close" dialog since it usually comes up prematurely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like [OS Monitor](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor) might do what you want. I believe it just uses the [`top`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top) utility to get process info. Screenshot:

[image]

And note that tapping on one of the rows will expand it to show info like memory use, priority, and so forth.